# Box2D - большое количество статичных объектов

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр, box2d, движок, тайл

Работаю над игрой-платформером на основе тайлов. Ниже приведу основные этапы во время выполнения для облегчения понимания проблемы.

Имеется массив в виде world[x][y], который определяет размеры нашего мира.
Этот массив забивается цифрами, которые соответствуют различным тайлам.

Тайлы представляют собой квадраты одинакового размера по W и H.

После этого вывожу все тайлы на монитор, соответственно, рядом прикручиваю функцию скроллинга карты и функцию отсечения того, что не попадает в саму видимую часть приложения, т.е. "не рисую того, чего не видно".

На этом этапе все отлично, работает как надо, любой размер мира не вызывает просадки FPS.

Пришло время добавить персонажа. По определенным причинам для проверки коллизий решил использовать готовый физический движок (Box2D).

Отлично. Создаю массив тел (под этим понятием в данным контексте я объединил b2Body, b2BodyDef, b2PolygonShape) в виде [x][y], после чего снова прогоняем массив по циклу, однако в этот раз задаем координаты и размеры тел.

В цикле отрисовки получаем координаты тел и на основе их вырисовываем тайлы. Все работает.

Но теперь меняем размеры мира и в итоге получаем... просадку FPS! И чем больше размер мира, тем сильнее FPS падает. 
Как я понял, это связано с большим количеством статичных объектов и я не имею понятия как именно оптимизировать этот момент. doSleep дает очень незначительный эффект.

Что можно сделать? Может быть, я делаю что-то не так?

Answer (score 1):

А каких статичных объектах идёт речь?

Как я понял у вас все "персонажи" активны и обрабатываются **ВСЕ в каждой итерации** игрового цикла - отчего скорее всего и идёт просадка FPS. В подобных платформерах обычно динамические объекты обрабатываются только те, которые попадают в активную часть карты. Или вообще создаются только, когда попадают попадают в активную часть карты, потом удаляются.

Попробуйте либо создавать/удалять движущиеся объекты динамически. Либо обрабатывать только видимые объекты в игровом цикле.

Во втором случае нужно ещё выбрать нужный тип коллекции, для быстрого доступа только к видимым объектам и быстрого вычисления/изменения параметра "видимость".

Comment: Это я и пытался сделать. Но из-за нехватки опыта не очень то и получалось.
Я отказался от Box2D и сделал простую проверку столкновений на AABB с тайлами, находящимися непосредственно рядом с игроком.